# How to avoid a Spring 6 non-fatal "TargetSource cannot determine target class" stacktrace output?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

We have a Spring application that defines some beans using a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. Using Spring 6 (Spring Boot 3), a non-fatal `INFO` level stacktrace is printed at startup like this:

```
2023-10-19T16:15:42.223+02:00  INFO 18756 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : FactoryBean threw exception from getObjectType, despite the contract saying that it should return null if the type of its object cannot be determined yet

org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: TargetSource cannot determine target class: Either an interface or a target is required for proxy creation.
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(DefaultAopProxyFactory.java:65) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
...
```

The same code works fine (without the stacktrace being output) in Spring 5 (Spring Boot 2). What the application does is basically

1. An `ApplicationContextInitializer` is configured
2. The initializer adds a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`
3. The processor defines a proxied service
4. The service is used; in Spring 5 **no errors** are shown, in Spring 6 the **stacktrace appears** - the application **works in both cases**

A small demonstration of the issue is shown here: https://github.com/smurf667/test-spring-boot3-aop-issue

Are we doing something wrong, or is this an issue/regression in Spring 6?

Comment: Thanks for the reproducer, but what is the real use case for something like `@Bean public String helloString(MyService service)`? It does not seem to make much sense to define a bean of type `String` which will forever return the same, cached String from its very first service call, even if the injected service would return a different result upon every call. That "bean" does not even have any meaningful methods you could call. Please explain and/or improve the example to resemble something a little more realistic.

Comment: Yes, that String bean is just a hack to demostrate the service is working; removing the bean will make no difference, since the stacktrace is output in Spring 6, but not in Spring 5. It is just used as proof that the app is operable in both Spring 5 and 6. Hope this part does not confuse.

Comment: It did confuse me, q.e.d. You are right, the bean is not necessary at all to reproduce the problem. So why include it in the sample project in the first place? To prove that the service works, you could simply have fetched the service bean in your main method and called its method. This way, both you and I lost time, me waiting for your response and today possibly not having enough time to look at cour sample code again. But eventually, someone else or maybe I hopefully find time to investigate and respond to your question. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not a definitive answer, but too much info to comment.*

I debugged in both Spring Boot versions, and what I found out is that the exception is caught and logged [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/cf10cee16a771f77396eefe7dac2ceab53c6cea1/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java#L47-L64).

The difference between Spring 5.3.29 (Boot 2.7.15) and Spring 6.0.12 (Boot 3.1.4) is that field `AdvisedSupport.targetSource` is set earlier in the old Spring version than in the new one, i.e. when the target source is checked in method `DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy`, it is already set in the old Spring version, but still an `EmptyTargetSource` instance in the new version, causing the exception to be thrown. Funny detail: The error log says that throwing an exception there violates a contract, which is why it is caught and logged.

I think, this is worth creating a Spring issue, asking for clarification if this is considered to be a bug, merely an annoyance or the problem sits in front of the computer, somehow using those context initialiser and bean factory post processors in a wrong or non-canonical way. I am not a Spring user at all and have zero knowledge about that stuff. I am interested in this question merely, because I am kind of an AOP expert. I also have no idea what your real factory is actually supposed to do. If you would just annotate and auto-wire your components canonically, at least in this example you would not need that functionality at all. I guess, your real situation is more complex than your minimal reproducer shows.

That the application works in both cases, is probably to be expected, because `DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy` for the same factory is called again later after the target source has been set already, the second and subsequent times not causing any exceptions anymore.

---

**Update:** [Spring issue #31473](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31473), createy by *@JanDasWiesel* according to my recommmendation, was resolved and the fix scheduled to be part of the upcoming Spring 6.0.14 release.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31473

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/f9be717602b954609bcba0a36495208d48d52a65 and should appear in the next release of Spring.

Comment: I do not feel it is particularly nice that, instead of commenting on and accepting my answer, you wrote another answer consisting of only a link and even accepted it. I did the leg work of analysing this for you and recommended to create the issue, the resolution of which you are now profiting from. If you want to motivate anyone to also invest time into your future questions, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: I wanted to communicate for everyone where to find the fix. Sorry if this offended you.

Comment: Read again what I wrote: Not your information sharing offended me. Your manners and lack of respect towards the people in this community who are trying to help you did. Thanks for accepting my answer instead. BTW, there was no need to tell everyone where to find the fix, because it is already linked to the issue you mentioned in your first comment. Instead, mentioning the actual release fixing the issue instead of "next release", the meaning of which changes over time, would have been helpful.

Comment: Suggestion: I  am going update my answer, mentioning the planned Spring release for the bugfix. That was exactly my plan when I noticed your answer, BTW. It was the reason why I reopened the page in the first place, because I had subscribed to the GitHub issue since you mentioned it. You were just faster and wrote an answer instead of a comment. Then, the information is preserved and you can delete your answer and all the comments with it. OK?

Comment: All good, please do so!

Comment: I did yesterday already. 